# Rid(riddle)dle For You!

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay

> Open the portal, pass through, will you?
> Energetic and unseen, yet you feel me too.
>
> I can be sharp, yet never sever,
> Seek, look, dig up, discover.
>
> In dire straits, seek my embrace,
> Five we are, to give you another to trace.

*I am a four letter word.*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are a

> MAZE (pretty clever)

Explanation

> Every line talks about a specific word. I got the hint from *"we are five"* phrase pointing to five lines above. So, let us see what we got here...

Open the portal, pass through, will you?

> ENTER

Energetic and unseen, yet you feel me too.

> WIND

I can be sharp, yet never sever,

> TURN

Seek, look, dig up, discover.

> FIND

In dire straits, seek my embrace,

> EXIT

Five we are, to give you another to trace.

> We get ENTER, WIND, TURN, FIND, EXIT. Uh, what next ?

Aha -

> The *title* suggests we have a *Riddle inside a Riddle* so these words are making a new riddle for us to solve. Enter -> wind through -> turn -> find -> Exit are all the actions related to a MAZE. So, yep, a MAZE.

Comment: You have successfully found your way through! Congrats :)